# Dask Dataframe Pivot Table Resulting in zero values

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I have the following dask Dataframe:

| id | category | alue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | Material | Metal |
| key2 | StorageType | Doors |

After pivoting

ddf.pivot_table(index='id ', columns='category', values='value')

The result:

| id | Material | StorageType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | - | - |
| key2 | - | - |

WHAT am I doing wrong? Really frustrating

Comment: What are you expecting happen?

Comment: Hey Paul I wanted for example for key1 to have within Material column - the value METAL. Could it be that pivot tables in dask can only process numbers in the value and not strings?

Comment: you have a typo in the dd header `alue` not `value`
your line should look `ddf.pivot_table(index='id ', columns='category', values='alue')`

Comment: hey @NoobVB I just didn't copy it into hear, of course it is value and not alue :)